# How do I make text file show its text on the icon?

Tags: nautilus, icons

As I remember, Ubuntu used to show part of the first lines of a text file in the preview when you had grid-of-icons view in Nautilus.

Now it's not showing it. It would be real handy to show the first part of the first lines, in cases where there are a bunch of similarly named files with ids in them.

Answer (score 2):

That feature was removed during GTK3 migration: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676531

> Remove text besides icons mode for icon view
>
> This doesn't really work well, it is inconsistent with the file
>   chooser, isn't use anywhere else in GNOME, and we want to enhance the
>   list view to cover this case.

Comment: Good find, I though I had seen that. So what is the solution?

Comment: Code it yourself, change your FM or forget about it.