# Ubuntu MATE: show text file contents on its icon in caja

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, caja

After upgrading from Mate 16.04 to Mate 18.04, there is no longer a few lines of preview printed on file icon. I liked that feature.

It it possible to achieve this in 18.04?

related: [How do I make text file show its text on the icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804926/how-do-i-make-text-file-show-its-text-on-the-icon)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm your issue on clean Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS.

All settings are set as in 16.04 LTS
[image: Preview preferences]

but Preview is not shown in Icon mode:
[image: No Preview in Caja 1.20 on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS]

So I reported [bug 1787368](https://bugs.launchpad.net/mate-desktop/+bug/1787368) to LaunchPad and posted a question to the [ubuntu-mate.community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/caja-does-not-show-previews-of-text-files-on-bionic-is-it-normal/17577?u=norbert_x).

Waiting for developers' reaction. Can't do more today.